# Solving a quadratic 9-equation system

Tags: quadratic-forms

I need to solve the following system:
$$\begin{cases}
A^TA=B &(1)\\ 
A\vec{x}=\vec{y} &(2)\\ 
\end{cases}
$$
I need $A$, given $B$, $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.

$A$ and $B$ are both 3-by-3 matrices; $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are 3-component vectors.

B is by construction a positive-definite matrix; $A$ is expected to be close to $I_3$.

In my problem, $B$ is actually the matrix defining the ellipsoid measured during the calibration procedure of a 3D sensor, and $A$ is the inverse of the sensitivity matrix to be found (it is not necessarily symmetric).

So we have 6 independent, quadratic equations in $(1)$ and 3 independent, linear equations in $(2)$ for 9 unknowns (the coefficients of $A$).

Does anyone have a clue about how to proceed to get an analytical solution?

Comment: Seems that a QR decomposition of A might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better than the **QR** decomposition I suggested above, the SVD decomposition might work. In fact, given
$$
{\bf A} = {\bf U}\,{\bf \Sigma }\;\overline {\bf V} 
$$
the system above becomes
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \overline {\bf A} \;{\bf A} = {\bf V}\,{\bf \Sigma }\;\overline {\bf U} {\bf U}\,{\bf \Sigma }\;\overline {\bf V}  = {\bf V}\,{\bf \Sigma }^{\bf 2} \,\overline {\bf V}  = {\bf B}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad {\bf B}\;{\rm diagonalizable} \hfill \cr 
  {\bf U}\,{\bf \Sigma }\;\overline {\bf V} \,{\bf x} = {\bf y}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \overline {\bf x} \;{\bf V}\,{\bf \Sigma }^{\bf 2} \,\overline {\bf V} \,{\bf x} = \overline {\bf x} \;{\bf B}\,{\bf x} = \overline {\bf y} \;{\bf y} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
so that **B,x,y** are not totally independent (for real solutions to exist).
Therefrom ${\bf \Sigma }$ and ${\bf V}$ can be obtained from the normalized eigenvalue decomposition of ${\bf B}$.
${\bf U}$ is the rotation matrix that brings ${\bf \Sigma }\;\overline {\bf V} \,{\bf x}$ in ${\bf y}$.

Comment: How do you compute the $\bf U$ that satisfies the equations in the original system?. The rotation matrix that brings $\bf \Sigma\,\overline V\,x$ into $\bf y$ is not unique.

Comment: Indeed, more specifically, $U$ is an orthogonal matrix but does not have to be a rotation matrix. In other words, it belongs to $O(3)$ but not necessarily to $SO(3)$.

Comment: Ok, got it, **all** of the solutions computed in this way satisfy the original equations, $\bf U$ can be any orthogonal matrix that takes $\bf \Sigma\,V^T\,x$ into $\bf y$. Great answer.

Comment: True. I realise my problem is actually underdetermined...

Comment: **U** orthogonal in general. But the physical nature of the application might suggest to exclude reflections (or maybe not if the sign of the measure is also under question, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

If you multiply the second equation by $A^T$ you get $A^T y = Bx$. One more multiplication by $A$ yields $A Bx = B y$. Now you can solve 9 by 9 linear sistem and check if the quadratic part is satisfied.

Comment: How do you assume that $A A^T = B$?, $A$ is not necessarily symmetric, according to the OP.

Comment: That one of the equations in the system, It is not true in general ofcorse.

Comment: In the system we have $A^T A = B$, not $A\,A^T = B$, without A being symmetric, $A^T A \neq A\,A^T$

Comment: I see, then it should be $B^{T}$ instead of $B$

Comment: No, not really, $A^TA = B$ does not imply that $A\,A^T = B^T$.

Comment: yes, transposition reverses the order of multiplication

Comment: $B = B^T$, you are saying that $A\,A^T = A^TA$, which is not true.

Comment: No, $A A^T = (A^T A)^T$ is what I am saying.

Comment: That's wrong, sorry.